# how to reassign page number in DJVU file?

Tags: linux, page-numbering, djvu

**Is there a simple way to renumber pages in a DJVU file?**

**Example:**
I've got a book, and page 1 is actually the cover, and so on, such that the actual page 1 of the book is at, say, 10 in the document; what I'd like to do is call them something like C,i,ii,..., and then 1,2,...

I know it can be done, since I've got other books in this format with this numbering, and I'd like to do it on Linux, better if via terminal.

Thanks,
N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to renumber

```
for (( i=11; i<=823; i++ ))
do
 djvused new.djvu -e "select $i; set-page-title $((i-10)); save"
done
```

to rename

```
djvused new.djvu -e 'select 2; set-page-title ii; save'
```

Comment: Here is a better alternative. First, use `echo` to dump the `select` and `set-page-title` pairs (without `save`) into a script file. Then call `djvused new.djvu -s -f script-file`. This alternative invoke the `save` command only once and is much faster.

Comment: I wrote a script to automatically generate the commands for both arabic and roman numbers, including optional cover and back options and skipped pages, on a similar question on unix.stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578110/224735

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly offtopic. Just in case someone needs to do the same thing on Windows using PowerShell:

```
for($i=11; $i -le 823; $i++){
  $j=($i-10)
  $args = "new.djvu -e ""select $i; set-page-title $j; save""" 
  write-host "djvused $args"
  start-process djvused $args -NoNewWindow -wait
}
```